# how to implement facebook conversion api based on which tracking pixel is ready (Nextjs)

Tags: facebook, tracking-pixel

My goal is to embed conversion api in my Nextjs project
And before that I've successfully implement tracking pixel
(I also have access token already)

I suppose that there is also a script that I have to load in ...

But I can't find the script.
I'm not sure whether I misunderstand something.